# Laravel 5.2 ajax pagination show duplicate result and blink 2 or 3 times

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

This is my controller code:

```
  $website = Website_links::where('website_id', $id)
            ->Paginate(5);
        $websites = Website::where('id',$id)->first();
        if (Request::ajax()) {
            return Response::json(View::make('user.project.audit_content', array('data'=>$website))->render());
        }
        return View::make('user.project.audit_content', array('data'=>$website));
```

And this is JavaScript pagination code:

```
  $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    if (window.location.hash) {
        var page = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
        if (page == Number.NaN || page <= 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            getPosts(page);
        }
    }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#link a', function (e) {
        getPosts($(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1]);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

function getPosts(page) {
    $.ajax({
        url : '?page=' + page,
        dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function (data) {
        $('.page-wrraper ').html(data);
        location.hash = page;
    }).fail(function () {
        alert('Posts could not be loaded.');
    });
}
```

And this is my view:

```
    @extends('layouts.master')
 @section('content')


<div class="main-wrapper nopad-lr ">

    <!-- .......................................................................
                          top  section
   ...........................................................................-->
    @include('layouts.topnav')
    @include('layouts.smallnav2')
            <!-- .......................................................................
                             Left section
      ...........................................................................-->
    <div class="left-sec">
        @include('layouts.sidebar',['active'=>$active])
    </div>
    <!-- .......................................................................
                     Right section
   ...........................................................................-->
    <div class="right-sec">
       {{--@include('layouts.topnav')--}}
       @include('layouts.innernav')

                <!--.................................... ......................................right conent....................................... -->
        <div class="page-wrraper  clear">
            {{--@include('layouts.innernav')--}}

            <div class=" main-table audit-meta clear">
                <table class="table table-blue">
                    <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <th style="border-bottom:1px solid transparent">Page Title & Canonical URL</th>
                        <th style=";text-align: center;" colspan="2">Links</th>
                        <th  style="width: 150px;border-bottom:1px solid transparent">Words Count</th>
                        <th  style="width: 76px;border-bottom:1px solid transparent" >Action</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <th  ></th>
                        <th style="width: 150px;text-align: center;" >External</th>
                        <th style="width: 150px;text-align: center;"  >Internal</th>
                        <th  ></th>
                        <th  ></th>
                    </tr>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($data as $meta)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$meta->meta_title}}
                            <a href="{{$meta->page_url}}" target="_blank">{{$meta->page_url}}</a></td>
                        <td>{{count($meta->type_external)}}</td>
                        <td>{{count($meta->type_internal)}}</td>
                        <td>2324</td>
                        <td>
                            <ul class="option-menu">
                                <li class="selected"><a><i class="icon-action_report"></i></a>
                                    <ul class="option-dropdown">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href=""><i class="icon-action_report"></i>Re-Crawl</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href=""><i class="icon-action_report"></i>Navigate</a>
                                        </li>

                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div id="link" class="pagination-sec">
                {!! $data->links() !!}
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- .....................................................................right conent end....................................... -->
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

@stop
```

Now pagination works correctly and page does not refresh, but this code replaces the whole page in to div which class=page-wrapper and blinks 2 or 3 times. I mean, I am getting sidebar top nav etc in div which class=page-wrapper.